# Ranking by category in R

Tags: r, ranking, sqldf

I have a data frame and I want to return a ranking for each `Category` based on `PCC`.

```
> head(newdf)
            ItemId    Category PCC
1       5063660193 Go to Gifts   2
2   24154563660193 Go to Gifts   1
2.1 24154563660193   All Gifts   1
3   26390063660193 Go to Gifts   3
3.1 26390063660193   All Gifts   3
4         18700100 Go to Gifts   1
```

I've initially though to do it using the `sqldf` package, but unfortunately a dependence (`tcltk`) is not available for R version 3.0.2.

With `sqldf` a call similar to the following should do the job:

```
# ranking by category
rank <- sqldf("select 
                 nf.ItemId,
                 nf.Category,
                 nf.PCC,
                 rank() over(Partition by nf.Category order by nf.PCC, nf.ItemId, nf.Category) as Ranks

               from 
                 newdf as nf

               order by 
                 nf.Category,
                 nf.Ranks")
```

Do you know any alternative I can use?

Comment: What specific behavior of `rank` do you want in the case of ties?

Comment: Read the troubleshooting section on the sqldf home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are only a handful of the different ways to do this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "            ItemId    Category PCC
       5063660193 'Go to Gifts'   2
   24154563660193 'Go to Gifts'   1
 24154563660193   'All Gifts'   1
   26390063660193 'Go to Gifts'   3
 26390063660193   'All Gifts'   3
         18700100 'Go to Gifts'   1",header = TRUE,sep = "")

library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(Category),transform, val = rank(PCC))

library(dplyr)
mutate(group_by(dat,Category),val = rank(PCC))

library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(dat)
setkey(dat1,Category)
dat1[,val := rank(PCC),by = key(dat1)]
```

Also, I am able to load **sqldf** on R 3.0.2 just fine, so I'm not sure what your problem there is.

This uses the default behavior of `rank`. See `?rank` and the `ties.method` argument to customize it to your exact needs.